# VSCode Typescript.NPM Warning for Babylon.js TS File

Tags: npm, typescript-typings, visual-studio-code, babylonjs

I use **VSCode** as an IDE for **Babylon.js**. To show `Babylon.js` code hinting, I was recommended to use "**babylon.d.ts**" file as the value of the "**typescript.npm**" in the VSCode's **User Settings**.

But when I hovered over a property in my JS script, a warning came up:

> Could not install typings files for JavaScript language features.
>
> Please ensure that NPM is installed or configure 'typescript.npm'
>
> in your user settings.

How to fix this error and show the code hinting for `Babylon.js` JS script on **VSCode**?

Answer (score 0):

to get babylon.js typings, just drop the babylon.d.ts file in your folder.
The file will be used by VSCode compiler directly

Comment: Yes, I have done it. I drop the "**babylon.d.ts**" file into the "*C:\wamp\www\Project_Folder*", where the "**index.html**" and the **JS** file are. There is no code hinting show up, so I use the "**babylon.d.ts**" file as the value of the "**typescript.npm**" in the VSCode's **User Settings**.